# Pandas group by number of months between number of months

Tags: python, pandas

I have sales information for different types of parts having different durations.I want to take difference in months when my date is in 'YYYYMM' format.
I have tried this.

```
(data.YYYYMM.max() - data.YYYYMM.min()
```

which gives me difference in days.how can I get this difference in months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'YYYYMM':['201505','201506','201508','201510']})

print (df)
   YYYYMM
0  201505
1  201506
2  201508
3  201510

df['YYYYMM'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYYMM'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('m')

a = df.YYYYMM.max() - df.YYYYMM.min()
print (a)
5
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks.Accepting this answer. Pandas doesn't have much documentation on dt.to_period. Like all options and examples.

Comment: Some information are in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-between-representations), but it is a bit hidden. Thank you.